# What is the right way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query that is not returning all the results it should.
I'm using Laravel, but the result is the same if I write the query directly in PHPMyAdmin:

```
clientpages::selectRaw('page as value, COUNT(ID) as `count`')
            ->where('page', 'like', '%blog%')
            ->orWhere('page', 'like', '%home%')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$range['from'], $range['to']]);
```

The problem is that the query only processes the first `like`. It only returns the pages that have `blog` in them and not the ones with `home`.
The culprit is the date condition. If I remove that, it works as expected, but what is the right way to use these three conditions all at once?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you would wrap a normal SQL query in parentheses, you can do the same in Laravel like this:

```php
clientpages::selectRaw('page as value, COUNT(ID) as `count`')
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where('page', 'like', '%blog%')
                ->orWhere('page', 'like', '%home%')
            })
            ->whereBetween('date', [$range['from'], $range['to']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$clientpages = DB::table('clientpages')
       ->where('page', 'like', '%blog%')
       ->orWhere('page', 'like', '%home%')
       ->whereBetween('date', [$range['from'], $range['to']])
       ->get(); //or count() if you just want the count

clientpages::where('page', 'like', '%blog%')
           ->orWhere('page', 'like', '%home%')
           ->whereBetween('date', [$range['from'], $range['to']])
           ->get(); //or count() if you just want the count
```